# Python map with function that returns variable number of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3, I have a function that returns a list of variable size

I would like to run this function over a list and concatenate the results.
for example::

```
def the_func(x):
    return [x]*x

def mapvar(f,v):
    ans=[]
    for x in v:
        ans.extend(f(x))
    return ans

print (mapvar(the_func,range(10)))
```

Is there a best practice in python to do this? if is there a standard mapvar function?

Comment: Isn't this the same as calling `map()` and then concatenating the result lists?

Comment: ^ Yes.  Best practice would probably be the nested list comp though.  `[v for i in range(10) for v in the_func(i)]`

Comment: @wim Agreed, since `reduce()` is deprecated ;)

Comment: @dhke `reduce` would also have quadratic behavior.

Comment: @dhke not really deprecated, but kicked out as a builtin function and moved to `functools` where it's hoped it never gets noticed :)

Answer (score 1):

What you've got looks good. I would just factor out `flatten` and use the builtin `map`.

```
def the_func(x):
    return [x] * x

def flatten(lst):
    return [x
        for subl in lst
            for x in subl]

print(flatten(map(the_func, range(10))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged [python-3.x], here is a one-liner using `map` for projection and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` for flattening:

```
import itertools
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(the_func, range(10))))
print(result)
```

This is about 1 second faster than the nested for list comprehension version (3.3 seconds vs. 4.1 second) on average using 1 mil. iterations.

Comment: @yigal You may also want to look at: [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) for a comparison of different flattening approaches.